# Separate chat message Left and Right base on user role

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make chat applition and I want to make little modification.
When admin is writing his/her message should go to the right side and when User is typing message should go to left side.

```
@if (ViewBag.discussion != null)
    {
        @foreach (var discussion in ViewBag.discussion)
        {
            <div class="direct-chat-msg @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "" : "right")">

                <div class="direct-chat-infos clearfix">

                    <span class="direct-chat-name @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "pull-right" : "pull-left")">@discussion.ApplicationUser.Name</span>
                    
                    <span class="direct-chat-name @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Manager" ? "pull-left" : "pull-right")">@discussion.DateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="direct-chat-text">
                    @discussion.Content
                </div>
            </div>
        }       
    }
```

I try a couple of soultion

```
<div class="direct-chat-infos clearfix">
    <span class="direct-chat-name @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "pull-right" : "")">@discussion.ApplicationUser.Name</span>
    <span class="direct-chat-name @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Manager" ? "" : "pull-right")">@discussion.DateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span>
</div>
```

And this also

```
<div class="direct-chat-infos clearfix">
    <span class="direct-chat-name @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "" : "pull-left")">@discussion.ApplicationUser.Name</span>
    <span class="direct-chat-name @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Manager" ? "pull-left" : "")">@discussion.DateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Any suggestion and comment how to make this working ?

Comment: what are the properties of `.pull-right` and `.pull-left` classes?

Comment: what do you mean by properties ?

Comment: What are the styles defined for those two classes?

Comment: Hmm I didnt include any properties for those tow classes

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example with html and css so that we can debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="chat-container">
  <div class="chat-divider">Chat:</div>
  <div class="chat-item-container chat-item-left">
    <div class="chat-item">Chat text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-divider">Chat:</div>
  <div class="chat-item-container chat-item-right">
    <div class="chat-item">Chat text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chat-container {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.chat-item-container {
  background-color: green;
}
.chat-item-container.chat-item-right {
    background-color: tomato;
}
.chat-item-container.chat-item-right .chat-item {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.chat-item {
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/sh-roen/pen/VwPmNdv?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

the clean way to achieve that is to use [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) associate with some conditions depending on what language you are using. Here is a basic exemple:

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
ul li{
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 12px 10px;
}
ul li.admin{text-align: right; background-color: grey; color: white}
ul li.user{text-align: left}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="admin">howdy!I am root, how can l help ypu today</li>
  <li class="user">hello my name is ....</li>
</ul>
```

From there on you can set classes using the backend language our what ever you want.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
ul li{
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 12px 10px;
 margin-bottom: 12px
}
ul li.admin{text-align: right;}
ul li.user{text-align: left}

ul li span{ padding: 12px 10px;}

ul li.admin span{background-color: grey; color: white; }

ul li.user span{background-color: green; color: white; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="admin">
    <span>howdy!I am root, how can l help ypu today</span>
  </li>
  <li class="user">
    <span>hello my name is ....</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```